# Using sysroot for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX'

Tags: xcode, scripting, xcode-build-phase

I am trying to add a new build phase and run a `.swift` build script to process files.

### When I try:

v Run Script

Shell /usr/bin/swift

```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
"${PROJECT_DIR}/BuildScript.swift"
```

---

Shell /bin/sh

```
/usr/bin/swift "${PROJECT_DIR}/BuildScript.swift"
```

---

In both cases, I get the following errors:

```
/<unknown>

/<unknown>:1:1 using sysroot for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX'

/<unknown>:1:1 unable to load standard library for target 'arm64-apple-macosx13.0'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this is a better way to reference my file:

```
xcrun --sdk macosx swiftc -parse-as-library ScriptTarget/main.swift -o ScriptTargetOutput
./ScriptTargetOutput
```

I found a [AF Swift Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXYOqEVYCbg&t=336s) discussing it.

I wrote a [medium article](https://scottlydon.medium.com/how-to-run-build-phase-swift-scripts-in-xcode-d07dc952f528) walking through the steps.